# blank values in inter column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with status_flag as int. I want to status_flag to have blank values .I am extracting other values from the view vwtable( the vwtable does not have status_flag values in it)
where I am going wrong here. please help. I am using sql server 2008.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Data(id, last_name,first_name,middle_init,alternate,birthdate_month,birthdate_day,birthdate_year,gender,status_flag)
select( [id],[last_name],[first_name],[middle_init],[alternate],[birthdate.month],[birthdate.day][birthdate.year],[gender],
coalesce(cast (status_flag  as varchar(1)),'') as status_flag
FROM vwtable
```

Comment: Since your Status_Flag column is of datatype INT, you can't insert a VARCHAR (eg. blank space ''). You can have integers or NULL.

Comment: Please put any error messages you get in your questions. These are extremely important.

Answer (score 1):

Your COALESCE expression evaluates to a varchar, which cannot be inserted into the status_flag column (which is an int).  A blank space ('') is not a valid value for an integer column.

You can't be blamed for not wanting to have nulls in your table.  Another option would be to treat some other value as empty (like 0 or -1) and then you use this COALESCE statement:

```
coalesce(status_flag, -1) as status_flag
```

### Edit

I just read your question again.  You said vwtable doesn't have status_flag values, but you're selecting status_flag from vwtable.  Maybe that's your problem.  Can you elaborate on the exact problem you're having?

If vwtable has a status_flag column, but doesn't have any values in it (i.e. they are all null), then you don't need the coalesce expression at all.  You can just insert your "blank" value itself.

Comment: @Jerrod, since the status_flag is int in the dbo.data table,  all the values I get is 0, I want to change the values for status_flag as blank(''). Can you please tell me how do I get blank value in that column. Also, you are right , view does not have a statusflag column. I tried putting the coalesce... in both insert and select statement, nothing seems to work.

Comment: You cannot put a blank in an int column any more than you can put the letter "A" in an int column.  Your only other option with an int column is to make the value null.